# making a single stacked bar with colors from each stack depending on the distribution frequency

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have a vector of the size 10000x1, which I reduced to 4400x1. I want to make a stacked bar with the single entries of this vector. Each segment of the stacked bar should be colored depending on the distribution frequency. For example: if a value is represented 10 times, it should almost be black. if its only 1, it should be light grey.

**1st problem:** When I use a small vector, I get a stacked bar. If I use the one I need to I get multiple bars instead of one stacked bar.

**2nd problem:** How can I make the bar use a gray scale to color them?

I tried to transpose my vector to 1x4400 which didn't change anything.

I used `bar(data,'stacked')` which works for the small vector (at least I get a stacked bar. To get a single bar I used:

```
test =  [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3];
bar([test; nan(size(test))],'stacked');
```

[image: this works]

```
size of data : 4400x1
bar([data; nan(size(data))],'stacked');
```

[image: this doesn't stack]

Comment: "This works" - when talking about plots, please show the plot! You can [edit] your question and embed the image. The cliché holds that a picture speaks a thousand words.

Comment: You are right, I added the pics.

Comment: Do you *really* want to plot 4400 colored boxes one on top of the other? I feel like there's probably a *much* better way to visualize whatever it is you're trying to visualize.

Comment: Where you say "this works" you have a row vector (1xN), where you say "doesn't stack" you have a column vector (Nx1). Is that the problem?

Comment: hello gnovice, i think i could make far less values out of them whe nrounding those values. you think that is  the issue?

hello chris, i tried transposing it (make it Nx1) but it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I enter your first example, with an 1x8 matrix:

```matlab
test =  [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3];
bar([test; nan(size(test))],'stacked');
```

I see the same plot you see. Then I transpose `test` to make it an 8x1 matrix:

```matlab
test = test.';
bar([test; nan(size(test))],'stacked');
```

and I see something similar to your second plot:

[image: non-stacked bars, occupying half the horizontal space]

Note how the NaNs cause the right half of the x-axis to have no bars.

Thus, to get stacked bars you need to have a **row vector**. However, your data is a column vector, a 4400x1 matrix. `data = data.'` will change that.

Nonetheless, it is likely that MATLAB is not able to make a stacked bar plot with 4400 elements. I'm trying this out on MATLAB Online, and I've been waiting for several minutes and still don't have a plot. In any case, there is no way you would become any wiser with such a plot. Don't do it!

---

Regarding your second question: you can change the plot color order to `gray`:

```matlab
set(gca,'colororder',flipud(gray(256)))
```

However, the stacked bars are not colored according to their value, they just use the colors of the list in turn.

---

A better solution would be to plot your data as an image:

```matlab
test =  [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3];
imagesc(test.')
colormap(flipud(gray(255)))
set(gca,'xlim',[0,2],'xtick',1)
```

[image: vertical bar with gray-scale boxes]

[I just realized you might want to straighten the y-axis, `imagesc` inverts it. Simply: `set(gca,'ydir','normal')`.]

Comment: this is an amazing answer. with this i can figure out how do deal with the amount of numbers. Tahnk you chris!